# Query 200-300 viewshed rasters from a vector layer with z-values with QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, viewshed

**What I got:**

- 200-300 invisibility depth viewshed rasters with information about how tall buildings can be without being visible from the viewshed points
- A vector layer with a planned building as a polygon with z-value (building height)
- QGIS 2.18.12

**What I want to do:**

- Query all my viewshed rasters with the planned building vector layer to find out if the planned building intersects with any of the viewshed rasters

Could anyone point out an appropriate way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert the Rasters to Vectors.
Then you can perform a spatial query.

To convert 200-300 rasters can be tricky, how large (filesize) are the rasters?

Comment: 687 MB for each raster. Would it be possible to convert the only vector layer to a raster and then perform a spatial query?

Comment: And on top of that I need to query the planned building to all of the rasters to find out from which points the building would be visible. Even if I where to vectorize all the rasters and use spatial query I would still have to do one spatial query for each raster. What I need to do is query them all at once. Otherwise I might as well check this manually.